# EF Core / AutoMapper - How to map related data when there is no corresponding collection in the scaffolded classes?

Tags: c#, automapper, scaffolding, ef-core-6.0

I have a SQL Server database where a custom approach was used to allow storing translations of specific columns for different languages. It works by the "main" table for an entity only containing the actual data for the entity, but no column for the entity name. Instead, there is an additional table just for the translations of the entity names. This table consists of a foreign key (the entity Id), a column for storing the language specififier (for example "en" or "fr") and a column for the translated name. Here is an example:

- Table for the entity `Product` (very simplified):

  | id | price |
  | --- | --- |
  | 1 | 4 |
  | 2 | 1 |
- Translation table for this entity:

  | product_id | language | product_name |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 1 | de | Brot |
  | 1 | en | Bread |
  | 2 | de | Apfel |
  | 2 | en | Apple |

When I call `Scaffold-DbContext`, the classes are generated like this:

```
public partial class TblProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public partial class TblProductTranslation
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public virtual TblProduct Product { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to use AutoMapper to map the data from both tables to objects of this class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Name { get; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

What I did so far is to simply query the entities from the `TblProduct` and `TblProductTranslation` tables, loop over them in a foreach-loop and then manually add the name translations like this:

```
foreach (TblProduct dbProduct in dbProducts)
{
    Product product = MapperBootstrapper.Instance.Map<Product>(dbProduct);
    dbTranslations.FindAll(translation => translation.ProductId == product.Id)
        .ForEach(
            translation => product.Name.Add(
                translation.Language,
                translation.ProductName
            )
        );
    products.Add(product);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this where I don't have to manually merge the data from both tables?

Answer (score 0):

I just check your scenario and used Translation List instead of Dictionary for Name. [Working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bpCQld)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<TblProductTranslation> lst=new List<TblProductTranslation>();
            lst.Add(new TblProductTranslation{ProductId=1,Language="de",ProductName="Brot"});
            lst.Add(new TblProductTranslation{ProductId=1,Language="en",ProductName="Bread"});
            lst.Add(new TblProductTranslation{ProductId=2,Language="de",ProductName="Brot"});
            lst.Add(new TblProductTranslation{ProductId=2,Language="en",ProductName="Apple"});
        
           List<TblProduct> products=new List<TblProduct>();
           products.Add(new TblProduct {Id=1,Price=4});
           products.Add(new TblProduct {Id=2,Price=1});
        
           var result = (from c in products
              select new Product
              {
                  ProductId=c.Id,
                  Price=c.Price,
                 Name=lst.Where(x=>x.ProductId==c.Id).Select(y=>new Translation(){Language= y.Language,ProductName=y.ProductName}).ToList()
              }).ToList();
        
          foreach(var item in result)
          {
            foreach(var item1 in item.Name)
            {   
              Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} , Price: {1}, Name: {2}",item.ProductId,item.Price,item1.Language+" - "+item1.ProductName);
            }
          }
    }
    public class TblProductTranslation
    {
      public int ProductId { get; set; }
      public int Price { get; set; }
      public string Language { get; set; }
      public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }
    public class TblProduct
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int Price { get; set; }
    }
    public class Product
    {
      public int ProductId { get; set; }
      public List<Translation> Name { get; set;}
      public int Price { get; set; }
    }
    public class Translation
    {
      public string Language { get; set; }
      public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose of using AutoMapper? Sure, in this example this would easily work but in the actual project I sometimes have to do this with entities that have like 20 attributes which I certainly don't want to map manually back and forth all the time (I will have to reverse this whole process later when data is also written back to the database).